# How to enable hardware video acceleration with an Intel graphics chipset on Ubuntu 17.10?

Tags: video, intel-graphics, vlc, hardware-acceleration

It seems, that with Ubuntu 17.10 something has changed with the hardware video acceleration. It's not working properly anymore out-of-the-box with an Intel graphics chipset, because videos played in VLC are stuttering. The terminal shows the following, when opening a video:

```
$ vlc
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella (revision 2.2.6-0-g1aae78981c)
[0000555baee879d8] core libvlc: VLC wird mit dem Standard-Interface ausgeführt. Benutzen Sie 'cvlc', um VLC ohne Interface zu verwenden.
Gtk-Message: GtkDialog mapped without a transient parent. This is discouraged.
[00007fcbd4008758] vdpau_avcodec generic error: unsupported codec 1211250229 or profile 1
Failed to open VDPAU backend libvdpau_i965.so: Kann die Shared-Object-Datei nicht öffnen: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
^CQObject::~QObject: Timers cannot be stopped from another thread
```

The same is true for Gnome's Video (Totem).

While installing Ubuntu `Install third-party software` was ticked on with an active internet connection.

Installing `libvdpau-va-gl1` and rebooting also didn't help. I'm running Ubuntu on Xorg, not Wayland.

In Ubuntu 17.04 it was sufficient to install `i965-va-driver` and optionally `vainfo`. Now, in Ubuntu 17.10, `vdpau` files like `libvdpau1` and `vdpau-driver-all` are also installed by default, although they are responsible for Nvidia's hardware acceleration.

According to `vainfo` everything is installed and detected properly:

```
$ vainfo
libva info: VA-API version 0.40.0
libva info: va_getDriverName() returns 0
libva info: Trying to open /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/dri/i965_drv_video.so
libva info: Found init function __vaDriverInit_0_40
libva info: va_openDriver() returns 0
vainfo: VA-API version: 0.40 (libva )
vainfo: Driver version: Intel i965 driver for Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile - 1.8.3
vainfo: Supported profile and entrypoints
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Simple            : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileMPEG2Main              : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264ConstrainedBaseline: VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264Main               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileH264High               : VAEntrypointEncSlice
      VAProfileH264StereoHigh         : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Simple              : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Main                : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileVC1Advanced            : VAEntrypointVLD
      VAProfileNone                   : VAEntrypointVideoProc
      VAProfileJPEGBaseline           : VAEntrypointVLD
```

The hardware is also fine:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [1179:fb31]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: duplicate of your other question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/985372/choppy-videos-and-animations-since-17-10?noredirect=1#comment1586281_985372

Comment: Yes, it's definitely connected and a result of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue had nothing to do with hardware video acceleration, but with a simple bug in the [System Monitor](https://github.com/elvetemedve/gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor/issues/36) Gnome Extension. Deactivating it makes everything smooth again.