# Choppy videos and animations since 17.10

Tags: xorg, video, 17.10, youtube, animations

After a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 installation all animations (like [this](https://imgur.com/gallery/fLfrx) or [this](https://eidoo.io/) one in the background) and videos (f.i. in VLC or on YouTube, like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRj34o4hN4I) one) do have a small stutter every second.

Interestingly, YouTube full-screen videos play smoothly, even in 1080p. If another window gets into the foreground (by Alt+Tab), when watching a video in full-screen, then the video begins to stutter again. Per second there is on short stutter.

When the same 1080p video is minimized into a normal browser window, then it lags again.

This is true for Firefox and the Opera browser.

I've never experienced something similar on previous Ubuntu releases with the same hardware.

I'm running Ubuntu on Xorg, not Wayland, because of [mouse lags](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966651/mouse-lagging-on-ubuntu-17-10) under Wayland.

How can I get rid of those lags and stutters respectively?

That's my hardware:

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -i VGA -A2
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [8086:0166] (rev 09)
    Subsystem: Toshiba America Info Systems 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller [1179:fb31]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
```

I'm really desperate and appreciate every help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: you'd analyze not enough CPU problems with `top`, not enough RAM problems with `free`, not fast enough disks with `iotop` not enough network bandwidth with `iptraf`. Is it neither of those?

Comment: CPU seems normal. 20% of RAM is free. SSD is quick enough, as is bandwidth. As said before, I never had problems with the hardware under 17.04 or previous versions. The really odd thing is that YouTube videos in full-screen, even in 1080p, play fine. If another window gets into the foreground (by Alt+Tab), when watching a video in full-screen, then it stutters again. Per second there is on short stutter.

Comment: duplicate of your other question here (?): https://askubuntu.com/questions/974250/how-to-enable-hardware-video-acceleration-with-an-intel-graphics-chipset-on-ubun

Comment: you might actually take this question to the ubuntu bugtracker

Comment: the symptoms here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1386721 look somewhat similar. Maybe you can find a hint there on how to fix your problem?

Comment: At the beginning I thought that there is an issue with the hardware acceleration, as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974250/how-to-enable-hardware-video-acceleration-with-an-intel-graphics-chipset-on-ubun), but now I assume, that it has another cause.

Comment: among the various interesting ideas in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-gnome/+bug/1386721 is the usage of `xdiagnose`. I think that might be worth a poke. Did you have a look at it maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily, I've found the reason by accident: It's due to a bug caused by the [System Monitor](https://github.com/elvetemedve/gnome-shell-extension-system-monitor/issues/36) Gnome Extension. Deactivating it makes everything smooth again.

Comment: I don't see this problem. I have system-monitor and youtube video full screen with another window in front. No problem. Idon't use the Intel driver though. I have a cheap AMD graphic card `Caicos [Radeon HD 6450/7450/8450 / R5 230 OEM]`